# How to log in Spark Java API as evaluation is Lazy?

Tags: java, logging, apache-spark

As the evaluation in Spark is lazy, the logs tracing the time to execute a statement could go wrong. For ex: if user captures start time before reading a text file and after file has been read(before and after sc.textFile()), it would lead to wrong information as the logging will be done but the file has not yet read due to lazy evaluation. Any solution to this, like lazy logging?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call a spark action on your *RDD* in order to trigger the effective computation. Transformation actions like: map, filter, read of a file etc will not trigger a spark action. In order to measure effective time between start-end logging put a spark action on the rdd (maybe you want to cache them for future use and call `rdd.cache()` )

Comment: Using spark action (like spark.count()) in logging will unnecessarily consume computation time which will also be counted. Thus, leading to wrong results of timings in logs.